# Mark MIlestone as completed

Tags: casemilestone, entitlements

I'm pretty new with Entitlement Process and Milestones. i WONDER if exists  a way to mark one Milestone as Completed and update the completion date when the Case exits the relative entitlement process.
For example: I have one Entitlement Process Call ' Case take in Charge' with 2 independent Milestones based on  Case's field  'Case Gravity'. If case Case Gravity = 1 Milestone is 20 minutes, if Case Gravity=2 Milestone is 40 minutes. When the Case status pass from NEW to Working I want the Case to exit the Entitlement process and the Mileston marks as completed with the appropriate completion date. Is it possible? (Below you find some picture)

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use process builder to do that!

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the behaviour you want previously by marking the milestone as completed via workflow. You should be able to do the same.

Comment: How did you do a workflow on milestone object? I'm not able to find it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update milestones with Workflow - Maybe Jannis meant Process Builder?

You can update and close milestones with Process Builder easey peasey